# Strange behavior of imports from local files in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Context**:

I had been developing some project in python and had decided to move functions which used to separate files (*functions.py*). I had created and imported it in my notebook.
After that I added some functions to the file.

After I had reloaded the cell with import I tried to run the cell with code, which uses composition from *functions.py*, and found out that it wasn’t imported.

I restarted the kernel and cell comiled.

Why didn’t notebook import my file wholly? Maybe because it caсhed first time and did not read the actual file again?

**Code of *functions.py*:**

```
def composition(f:callable, g:callable) -> callable:
    def cmp(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return cmp
```

**Code of *project.ipynb*:**

Cell 1:

```
from functions import *
```

Cell2:

```
s = composition(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**4)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_21766/3463491651.py in <module>
----> 1 s = composition(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**4)

NameError: name 'composition' is not defined
```

I use **python 3.8.10 64-bit** and editor is **Visual Studio Code 1.61.2**

Comment: Once the kernel is started you can only import a package once. Re-loading it won't work as the kernel takes the already loaded version - as was your suspicion. You have to restart the kernel in order for the updated file to import correctly.